# Why unable to edit ArcSDE from multiple computers on LAN using custom ArcGIS Engine application?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-engine

I cannot edit an ArcSDE database from multiple computers on a LAN network using a custom ArcGIS Engine application, I have tried both versioned and non-versioned feature classes, but they cannot be edited from more than one computer.

Inside the custom ArcGIS Engine application, for every single operation (Create, Remove), I open and close an edit session.

Any advice or experiences are welcome as why I may be unable to edit an ArcSDE database from multiple computers on a LAN network using a custom ArcGIS Engine application?

I tried to edit the same feature classe from 2 computers in the same time , but when i closed the edit session in the second computer, it gimme this error `Your edits could not be saved because the target version has been updated since you started editing. These edits have been merged into your edit session. Review the changes and save again.`

i'm editing feature classes like in this example :

```
    IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)DB_Access.get_obj().ws;
    workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
    workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

        IFeatureClass fc = DB_Access.get_obj().ws.OpenFeatureClass("points");

        IFeature f = fc.CreateFeature();

        f.set_Value(fc.Fields.FindField("name"), "name_of_point");

        f.Shape = geometry;
        f.Store();

        workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();

        workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

Comment: it returned an error when you start editing from multiple machines ?

Comment: it returns nothing but it cannot save the edits

Comment: Do all users have an Editor or Advanced license?

Comment: yes they have all advanced licence

Comment: What edit operation are you performing, as in what interface and method are you using (`ITable.Update`, `ITableWrite.DeleteRows`)?  How are you starting and stopping the edit session (`IWorkspaceEdit`, `IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit`)?  What do you mean you cannot save the edits?  Do you get an exception?  Or are you checking something like `IWorkspaceEdit.HasEdits`?

Comment: i have edited my question to answer your questions.

Comment: What is the error code if the resulting COMException? Is it FDO_E_VERSION_REDEFINED as discussed [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m89000000)?

Comment: It's all about versioning. When you're editing just one version from several computers, some kinds of post/commit errors can occure.

Comment: and how i can solve this problem please ?

Comment: "Right" way (by design from Esri): each editor is using his own version. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000t7000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using [IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000004sp000000).

```
IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)DB_Access.get_obj().ws;
IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit multiuserWSE = (IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit)workspaceEdit;
multiuserWSE.StartMultiuserEditing(esriMultiuserEditSessionMode.esriMESMVersioned);

workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

IFeatureClass fc = DB_Access.get_obj().ws.OpenFeatureClass("points");

IFeature f = fc.CreateFeature();

f.set_Value(fc.Fields.FindField("name"), "name_of_point");

f.Shape = geometry;
f.Store();

workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();

workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  You may want to look over [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/00010000010s000000.htm) section of the doc.  Editing through ArcObjects can be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

This is a licensing issue. A standalone ArcEngine license does not support multi-user editing. According to [ESRI's documentation](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geodatabase/multi-user-geodatabase), multi-user editing geodatabase functionality only exists for ArcGIS Server licensing.

Since you have tagged this question with ArcGIS Server, I am going to assume that you have an ArcGIS server license. What you need to do is ensure that both you ***and your users*** have the [ArcGIS Geodatabase Update Extension](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/67e593ac-55a5-41e0-9e7d-6530be4bc95c.htm#GeoExt) installed. You need this to create a multi-user geodatabase and also to enable multi-user editing.

**1.** If you haven't yet verified that the geodatabase you are working with is actually a multi-user database, check this. If it isn't a MU Geodatabase follow [this guide](http://www.esri.com/news/podcasts/transcripts/migratingfromsingleusergeodatabasestomultiusergeodatabases.pdf) (essentially just create an empty multi-user geodatabase and import all your single-user geodatabase information into it).

**2.** Verify that all users have the necessary geodatabase update extension mentioned above installed on their computer.

Comment: i have already a multi user geodatabase with "geodatabase update extension", and arcgis server licence in server and client computers. i think that i should create a version for each user then reconcile all versions, i wish to find better manner than this.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that - multi-user geodatabases should support multiple users editing a single feature class inherently. This leads me to believe that this is an ArcGIS Engine specific issue. Does multi-user feature class editing work fine outside of your custom ArcEngine application?

Comment: yes i was missing the IMultiuserWorkspaceEdit, thanks a lot  @Conor